# How to reduce the chance of being manipulated?

Tags: social-psychology, personality

What makes some people more suseptible to manipulation and having their opinions swayed relative to others? Are there character traits which highlight who might be more easily manipulated, or is it a frame of mind?

And in either case, how might someone that is easily manipulatable change their behaviour and/or frame of mind to protect themselves from being so?

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. We work differently to most SE sites, where we have a strict policy that all questions should [show evidence of prior research](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/993). Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google? This helps to provide an answer which will be more helpful.